# In maven, what's the purpose of put dependency in the aggregation pom.xml if it's not a parent pom?

Tags: java, maven

I have a maven project which has a structure below:

ROOT(aggregation pom.xml)

- A ( sub module of ROOT )
- B ( sub module of ROOT)

ROOT is NOT the parent project of A and B.

and I saw that there is some dependency libs in ROOT, is that necessary?
what's the purpose of declare dependency in aggregation pom if it's not any submodule's parent module?

I suspect that this is a wrong way to declare dependency in maven by previous project developer.

Comment: Is it a `dependencies` section immediately in the `project` root, or in a `dependencyManagement` section?

Comment: it's dependencies in a dependencies tag pair in a dependencyManagement tag pair.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `dependencyManagement` section declares the versions of dependencies, so sub-modules can use those dependencies without explicitly declaring their versions. That is, the sub-modules will have to declare the dependency they need, but they can leave out the `version`-tag.

This is especially useful in projects that have a lot of sub-modules with common dependencies: you only have to declare the versions in one place, which makes it easier to manage versions, and avoids having diverging dependency versions. It can also be used to manage (override) versions of the dependencies of dependencies.

If the root is not the parent of the sub-module, I don't think this works (I think that is an odd design though), but I think it should be possible to import the root as a BOM in the case. That is, in the sub-module, you'd add:

```xml
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>your-group-id</groupId>
            <artifactId>ROOT-artifact-id</artifactId>
            <version>your-version</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

Comment: according to the dscription above, I think the dependencyManagement section in the ROOT pom takes no any effect. It could be just something which can be removed but not be done yet.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood things correctly, then I think the previous developer was aggregating common dependencies to be shared among the two projects. This would make it so they both used the same dependencies.

Comment: but if the aggregation pom is not the parent pom of its submodule, could the dependency still be used by its sub-module when build the sub-module?

Comment: @柯鴻儀 I guess not.